# Overlapping markers/labels in Google Map API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a google map with several markers/labels placed very very close to eachother.
So close, that if the zoom-level is at a certain level all the labels are overlapping.

In order to be able to read all the labels when the map loads and when the zoom-level changes, I want to place the marker with a certain offset of the actually point with a line drawn to it.

I have tried to implement the "OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier" by George MacKerron, but according to the author himself, it can't be done using his code (due to the fact that his code is tied to an "onClick" listener and can't be executed during loading of the map or change of zoom-level)

I hope the above description is understandable dispite the fact that english is not my native language.

Comment: could you set up a fiddle so we can see your code?

Comment: We don't really need a fiddle here. There is an option, and the developer says it won't work: https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier/issues/2

Comment: How many markers do you have that need to be spread around? Is it like 5 or 10, or is it like 100 or 500? Just to get an idea... And when you say *all the labels are overlapping* you mean, all the marker icons?

Comment: I'm not  familiar with setting up a fiddle. Can't getting it to work.
You can see a live demo here : http://v5.trackline.dk/test5.php

Comment: @MrUpside: I guess i'll have a maximum of 20-30 markers i need to spread around

Comment: This issue was reported in the public issue tracker as well: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=10816